# Is it possible to use servers to mine bitcoins?

Tags: mining-profitability, cpu-mining, gpu, server

I have a vps, it's debian but i can install any os, i don't use it a lot, can i use it to mine bitcoins? Correct me if I'm wrong, bitcoins uses video cards, and as far as i know, vps and dedicated servers don't have video cards.

So therefore I'm asking, is it possible to use servers to mine bitcoins

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is CPU mining even worth it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-it)

Comment: Are you asking if it is technically possible, or just whether or not to consider it.

Comment: @StephenGornick i'm asking if it's technically possible, and if yes, then is it a good practice or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but not profitable.  Even if you consider the server as already paid for you will not generate nearly enough of a hashrate to earn more than a few cents a month.

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago I read about using amazon cloud instances when the value vs. effort made it profitable to mine with them, but that was before GPU-mining took over.

To be competitive today a service provider would have to employ ASICs. There would also be some economical overhead of providing the customer service, instead of just mining. Strict bitcoin mining operations like for example ASICminer have an advantage over that.

Comment: No, it was after. Still unprofitable, though. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8405.0

Answer (score 0):

Mining Bitcoin is possible, but almost certainly not profitable if it's the sole purpose of the VPS. You may, however, find profitability in other altcoins, such as Litecoin or Bytecoin.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; bad idea

I rented a VPS to do data analysis on the blockchain, so I ran a bitcoin client, which can have a heavy disk IO, and bitcoin-abe, which is similarly heavy due to a database backend. I loaded both bitcoind and mysql through libeatmydata to lessen the load (less syncs). I wasn't mining. Within a couple of hours, the provider suspended my account due to "bitcoin mining". I complained but they never unsuspended me.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with CPU mining is that before you manage to finish a share the block becomes stale - you barely get anything out as far as I can tell.

Comment: Like mining for actual blocks, there is no concept of progress 'toward' a share. Each hash is equally likely to result in a share.