# How much memory and bandwidth does bitcoind take up on a CentOS Linux system?

Tags: bitcoind

I'm thinking about installing [bitcoind](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) on my web server that runs on [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS). How much memory and bandwidth might it take up and would it affect my other sites on my server?

Comment: Are you sure that [CPU mining is worth it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/59/3930)

Comment: not mining... just installing for ecommerce site

Answer (score 1):

I run bitcoind 0.8.3 on a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). In May and June, the VPS used between 250 and 300 GB of bandwith per month. Most of that (~98%) was incoming traffic.

I'm not sure if all traffic is due to bitcoind. Of course, we ran updates on the server. But it is only used for bitcoind. No other webservices are active.

Comment: That seems extremely high, given that the transactions recorded in the block chain typically amount to just a few megabytes per day.

Comment: It's not high at all.  My bitcoind-only server generated 154gb of outbound traffic *in the last 7 days*.  12.73gb inbound traffic. I have 89 connections right now, and I've had over 150 in the past. If you're a stable, well-connected node, you will use a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: So clearly it's not just the bandwidth consumed in passively receiving the blocks, but the one spent in retransmitting them as well plus the wasted one in receiving/rebroadcasting blocks that ultimately get orphaned...

Comment: You have it set to way more than the default number of connections, which I believe is 8. I understand there is some debate over the benefits of doing that.